# In Angular, can I bind the emited output of a component directly to a property?

Tags: angular, typescript, eventemitter

My main application component interacts with sub components through `@Output` decorated properties on the subcomponent.  The output properties use and `EventEmitter<>()`.  Often the property emits a simple boolean or number.  I would like to bind this output directly to properties in the main application.  But am failing to do so.

What I am doing at the moment is:

```
//In my sub component:
@Output() subProperty = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

//In my main template:
<sub-component (subProperty)="setPropertyValue($event)"></subcomponent>

//In my main component (this I would like to avoid):
setPropertyValue(event) {
    this.mainProperty = event;
}
```

What I wanted to do was avoid the function in my main component and bind directly to my property, but the below code doesn't work:

```
//In my sub component:
@Output() subProperty = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

//In my main template:
<sub-component (subProperty)="mainProperty"></subcomponent>
```

Is there anyway I can avoid the additional function in my main component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the best you can do is this:

```
(subProperty)="mainProperty = $event"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the suffix `Change` to the end of your property so you can use the banana/football in the box syntax. A matching input is not required and will be ignored.

```
//In your sub component:
@Output() subPropertyChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

```
//In your main template:
<sub-component [(subProperty)]="mainProperty"></subcomponent>
```